# Installing from command line

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a way by which you can  automate an install from command line?

For example, like installing iTunes only using command line.

Answer (score 6):

Yes =)

For most installers, typing `installer.exe /passive` or `installer.exe /silent` will run the installer in unattended mode, which requires no user input or interaction.

If running the installer with an option like /? or /h (/help) does not list any options, it is usually possible to identify the installer software in the GUI it spawns and [research which command line arguments that installer-binary will accept](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php).